# Hex code of an error

Tags: c++, c

Runing Backtrace, It shows an error. What does the hexadecimal number represent at the end of a this line:

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x8e)[0x323aa337de]
```

Comment: I think this is actually a legit question.

Comment: The value of the RIP register, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The address at the end (`0x323aa337de`) is value of the program counter (the RIP register on x86-64).  According to your debug symbols, this address is equal to `__cxa_finalize+0x8e`, i.e. 0x8e bytes past the start of the `__cxa_finalize` function within the C runtime shared library (`/lib64/libc.so.6`).

Answer (score 2):

In Library, `lib64/libc.so.6`, function `__cxa_finalize` is currently being executed.
You are at 142 bytes (`0x8E`) in from the start of the function.
This is at memory address `0x323aa337de`.

This is either where the program crashed, or the instruction you are currently looking at in the debugger (depending on context).